# How to split maven tasks between tasks and pipelines without running redundant maven tasks

Tags: maven, maven-3, go-cd

I'm trying to set up a deployment pipeline using GoCD as follows:

1. Compile, test and deploy to Maven repo

   1. Check out source code from SVN
   2. Run mvn clean compile test install
   3. Run mvn deploy to deploy the WAR artifact to Sonatype repo
2. Deploy to Tomcat server

   1. Retrieve WAR artifact from Sonatype repo
   2. Run mvn tomcat7:redeploy to deploy it to the Tomcat instance I have running

The thing is, I can't seem to split 1.2 and 1.3 (for example) without having to rerun the whole the entire source code checkout again in 1.3. This seems redundant to me as I had already gotten it up to the package stage and should be able to just continue to run from there.

Between 1.3 and 2.2, I can see that it can retrieve the WAR artifact from Sonatype, but I can't do much with it with maven because there's just no pom.xml for me to execute the maven task with. Of course, I can just add the source code material and run the entire mvn package tomcat7:redeploy cycle again, but I'm pretty sure that's not what this was designed for initially.

I can also write a shell script and ask Go to run it to copy the WAR file to the right location, but again, I could have done everything in one maven pass and save myself some effort but that would just reduce the entire pipeline to a single box which isn't much help to help visualize the deployment pipeline.

Can I get some advice on how I should be designing this pipeline if I wanted to split a maven task flow into different Go tasks / pipelines?

Thanks
Wong

Comment: What is the intention of separating 1.2 and 1.3 ? If you do `mvn deploy` the life cycle contains `install`...?

Comment: At this point of time, there's not much to separate 1.2 and 1.3. But I do know that I have many scenarios where I want to create a separate WAR file for deployment into different environments so I may end up running a separate package/install/deploy for SIT, UAT environments etc. 1.2 will then be dedicated just for the surefire test stage and I run a few packaging tasks for environment specifics.  This is just my idea at this point of time, needs some work still of course.

Comment: You should create those different packages for different environments with a single run. You can simply run 1.2 and 1.3 with a single `mvn deploy` and make the creation of the environment specific things running in the same build...(http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2011/07/29/maven-configuration-for-multipe-environments/)

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks. Can I ask how would that transition to pipeline 2 then when I want to retrieve the WAR artifacts from Sonatype n deploy them using mvn? Thanks

Comment: You can either use the maven repository feature of Jenkins which can provide a maven repository which you can reuse in the second step or you can simply download them from your repository manager and make the deploy...